# Textfile.txt hyperlink not functioning in html? Not clickable

Tags: html, css, text, hyperlink

I put my resource.txt txt file with a link in it to the website I am trying to recreate as a reference. When I go to click on the text file in the html browser it shows up as a blue link that does not open when clicked, even when it is just plain text in the text file.

I should be able to click this text link am I right?

Could someone please help me with linking a clickable text file inside html?

Thanks for assistance in advance.

Here is my html:

<a *href*="resource/resource.txt"> Resources </a>

inside the resource.txt is a link to the reference website.

*Tried changing the link to plain text. Didn't work*

Comment: Not a big issue if this isn't resolved as long as I have the text file in the folder I am ok

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the file structure of your project you may be accessing the wrong file path.  When hovering over the location of your resources.txt file right click on it, if you are using vs code and select copy relative path.

Comment: Its the right path when I ctrl + click on it, if that what you mean. It opens up the link in text file in Vs editor.

Comment: when you right click on your resources.txt file in your code editor.  there should be a option that says copy relative path and it will give you a file path and paste that in your href @man-1 has suggested similar solution above as well.  

https://stackoverflow.com/a/74831051/20311183